# Select hundreds of rows by row number in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with about 11,000 rows. I have a list of about 700 row numbers that I want selected. They are somewhat random; not a specific 'range' of numbers.

Is there an easier way then scrolling through the spreadsheet and selecting these rows one by one?

The list of row numbers is in a .csv file, if that helps.

Thanks!

Possible solutions I'd like to implement: VB, C#, or something in Excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you plan on doing with these rows? If you're looking for a VBA solution, I suggest taking this idea a step or two further.  This is because it's not recommended to use `.Select` in code, but if it's simply that you're trying to get the row numbers and see the row, then it's fine...just a note.

This will take your row numbers, which I assume have been opened already and are in column A, from A1:A[whatever] without any breaks:

```
Sub test()
Dim lastRow As Integer, i As Integer, k As Integer
Dim rowNums() As Variant
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range

lastRow = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1))

ReDim rowNums(1 To rng.Count)

rowNums = rng.Value

Dim addRows As Integer

For i = LBound(rowNums) To UBound(rowNums)
    If i >= rng.Count Then Exit For
    addRows = Range(Cells(rowNums(i, 1) + 1, 1), Cells(rowNums(i + 1, 1) - 1, 1)).Count
    'Range(Cells(rowNums(i, 1) + 1, 1), Cells(rowNums(i + 1, 1) - 1, 1)).Select
    Range(Cells(rowNums(i, 1) + 1, 1), Cells(rowNums(i + 1, 1) - 1, 1)).EntireRow.Delete
    For k = LBound(rowNums) To UBound(rowNums)
        rowNums(k, 1) = rowNums(k, 1) - addRows
    Next k
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, if I could, I would just want to cut out all the other rows and be left with just a new table of the 700ish rows I was looking for. But really, two paths to get to the same place.

Comment: So, let's say your list has rows 2,3,5,6,100.  You want to delete all other rows, and keep only what's in rows 2,3,5,6, 100?

Comment: @Christopher - see my post, I updated the code to delete the ranges that aren't given.  Make sure to run this with some sample/fake info just to make sure it runs okay.l